# Is there a sorted Map that can replace keys

Tags: java, dictionary, replace, treemap, sortedmap

Are there any Java libraries that have a sorted `Map` (such as `TreeMap`) but has the ability to replace `keys`? For example I'm looking for something that could replace `treeMapInstance.firstKey()`. Speed is reasonably important which is why I'm not one for storing values, deleting, then placing values back in a new key.

In my application I may have an object such as

```
TreeMap<Long, Double> foo = new TreeMap<Long, Double>();
```

Sometimes I would like to change a key in `foo` without altering the associated value.

```
foo.put(1l, 1.0);
foo.put(2l, 2.0);
```

In the above for example how could I change the `key` `1l` to `5l` efficiently?

Comment: What's your specific functional requirement?

Comment: The structure of a TreeMap reflects the result of comparisons among its keys. A change in the value of one of its keys might break the invariants on which it depends for its speed.

Comment: what do you mean by "replace keys"? provide an example

Comment: If you care about speed, the speed of delete and insert is the same as rename. Cause these values are sorted (in trees usually) and renaming means, that they have to remove them from position they are and added to the position it should be with new key..

Comment: Changing 1l to 5l with 2l as an existing key would require a restructuring of the tree. 1l belongs to the left of 2l. 5l belongs to the right of 2l.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a `TreeMap`, [both `put()` and `remove()` are `O(log n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), so removal followed by addition is a very good starting point. If I were you, I'd use that and then profile the application to see where the actual bottleneck is. My money is on it being someplace else.

Comment: And I don't think the add/remove combination does any more work than would be needed to do a change in key while preserving the TreeMap structure.